# Java creating augmented array of size 400,000,000

Tags: java, array

I was solving one competitive coding question having integer bounds `2^100`. Fortunately, it was a dp question and I didn't need an array of that size. Practically we cannot create an array of size more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

> But I was thinking of creating a multidimensional array and treat it as a one-dimensional array.

what I need was a very large array with `O(1)` retrieval time. So Internally it will be a multidimensional array but I will treat it as a one-dimensional array.

#### So the size of the resultant array will be n*n.

> if n is Integer.MAX_VALUE then the resultant augmented array will be of Integer.MAX * Integer.MAX

Here what I did to implement this idea.

### BigArray class

```
public class BigArray
{
    
    private int[][] arr;
    private int row=0;
    private int col = 0;
    private int size;
    public BigArray(int size)
    {
        arr = new int[size][size];
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

### add method

```
public void add(int data)
    {
     if(row > size-1)
        {
            col++;
            row=0;
            this.arr[col][row] = data;
            row++;
        }
        else
        {
            this.arr[col][row] = data;
            row++;
        }
    }
```

### get method

```
public int get(int pos)
    { //get value in O(1)
        if((int) Math.sqrt(pos) > size)
            return -1;
        int col1 = pos/(size);
        int row1 = pos%(size);
        return arr[col1][row1];     
    }
```

But If I pass `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in `BigArray` it throws `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit`
maximum size I've tried is 20,000 so resultant size will be 20,000 x 20,000 = 400,000,000.

#### But if add one more dimension to this array I'll get more space.

if BigArray has `arr[][][]` resultant size will be n x n x n;
if BigArray has `arr[][][][]` resultant size will be n x n x n x n; and so on.

#### I know I had to implement necessary methods as I add a new dimension to the base array.

But I would like a review on this type of storage class. I don't know

> what's the maximum dimensions java array can have?

Also, do tell me

- if can use this approach to create arrays size more than the traditional array size
- Future scope such as generic BigArray of character will create string greater size
- other opinions/suggestions on this approach

Comment: How big of an array are you actually aiming for? Multidimensional with Integer.MAX_VALUE each dimension would be huge

Comment: Yes Im trying create array of size larger than Integer.MAX

Comment: Is it not an option to just use streams for the challenge? It doesn't seem practical to try and have that much stored at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An int is 32 bits? Then your 400,000,000 array requires ...

... 1,600,000,000 bytes == 1,600,000 KB == 1,600 MB == 1.6 GB

Have you configured your JVM to have that much RAM? You need some overhead for the application, so I'd probably configure 1.76 GB or so.

Comment: Any Idea how to configure? is it by means configurations or java code ?

Comment: First hit on google. It's a standard command-line feature for all JVMs (e.g. "-Xms"). But if you're using an IDE, your IDE will have a setting for this. If you're using an unusual JVM, it will have a custom setting for this. You need to read your JVM docs.

Answer (score 6):

The biggest problem I can see with this approach, is that a user can't `add` or `get` any index higher than `Integer.MAXVALUE`.  You might need to parse `Strings` or use a `BigInteger` type instead of `int` for those methods.

Answer (score 3):

Have you increased the size of your VM?  If not, you will not get past `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit` without doing something creative like storing the array in a file.

Do you need 4-byte integers, or would 2-byte shorts be sufficient?

This is allocating all the memory in one chunk:

```
arr = new int[size][size];
```

Perhaps you should use:

```
arr = new int[size][];
arr[0] = new int[size];
```

to allocate one chunk to hold the columns, one chunk to hold the first column, and then as data is being added, allocate new columns on demand:

```
public void add(int data) {
    if (row >= size) {
        arr[++col] = new int[size];
        row = 0;
    }

    arr[col][row]  = data;
    row++;
}
```

Using a variable size, or even `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to partition data into rows, columns, and higher dimensions is inefficient.  I’d use a hard-coded power of 2, to allow efficient module arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer [@tinstaafl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/33306/tinstaafl) [provided](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/230233/15863), I think that your class doesn't behave like arrays are implemented: namely, it is allocated in different places in the program's memory space. You can't, for instance, call `System.arraycopy()` to make a copy out of it.

I think that you implement here a specific `Map`, with keys as integers (or longs, as mentioned), and values as integers.